# How to enforce a coexistance relationship in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, database-design

Tables: `group`, `target`, `subgroup`, `subgroup_target`

`group` has many `target` 
`group` has many `subgroup` 
`subgroup` has many `subgroup_target` 
`target` has many `subgroup_target`

The relationship I want to enforce is that a `subgroup` always has the same number of `subgroup_targets` as its owning `group` has `targets`. In other words, if a `group` has 5 `targets`, each one of its `subgroups` must also have exactly 5 `subgroup_targets`. Additionally, within a given `subgroup`, each one of its `subgroup_targets` must correspond to a different `target` (they're basically the `subgroup's` version of each of the `group's` `targets`). You can think of the `subgroup_targets` as an array that is shadowing the array of `targets` the `group` has.

Is there a way to constrain the data such that a `target` cannot exist unless its corresponding `subgroup_targets` do as well? For example, if a `group` has several `subgroups` and a new `target` is inserted for that `group` what is a schema configuration that would result in the transaction failing if a new `subgroup_target` wasn't also inserted for each of the `group's` `subgroups`.

Below you'll find my preliminary design of the schema. As you can see it permits adding a `target` for a `group` without also adding a corresponding `subgroup_target` that links to it for each of that `group's` `subgroups`.

```
CREATE TABLE group(
        group_id                        INTEGER         NOT NULL,                
        PRIMARY KEY(group_id)
);

CREATE TABLE target(
        target_id                       INTEGER         NOT NULL,
        group_id                        INTEGER         NOT NULL,
        index                           INTEGER         NOT NULL,
        input                           BLOB            NOT NULL,
        output                          BLOB            NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(target_id),
        FOREIGN KEY(group_id) REFERENCES group(group_id),
        UNIQUE(group_id, index)
);

CREATE TABLE subgroup(
        subgroup_id                     INTEGER         NOT NULL,
        group_id                        INTEGER         NOT NULL,           
        index                           INTEGER         NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(subgroup_id),
        FOREIGN KEY(group_id) REFERENCES group(group_id),
        UNIQUE(group_id, index)
);

CREATE TABLE subgroup_target(
        subgroup_id                     INTEGER         NOT NULL,
        target_id                       INTEGER         NOT NULL,
        output                          BLOB            NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(subgroup_id, target_id),
        FOREIGN KEY(subgroup_id) REFERENCES subgroup(subgroup_id),
        FOREIGN KEY(target_id) REFERENCES target(target_id)
);
```

Comment: A bit tough to follow your schema, but you might want to look into using triggers here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I looked at triggers and unfortunately they don't provide validation at the level of the transaction. I would be able to use them to automatically insert a `subgroup_target` whenever a `target` is inserted, but I'm not looking for a solution that results in the database inserting data into itself. In my setup data manipulation is solely performed at the application level, so the functionality I'm looking for are constraints that can be applied to the schema such that data integrity is enforced not coerced.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Group GRP exists.
--
group {GRP}
   PK {GRP}
```

```
-- Subgroup number SG# of group GRP exists.
--
subgroup {GRP, SG#}
      PK {GRP, SG#}

FK {GRP} REFERENCES group {GRP}
```

```
-- Target TGT exists.
--
target {TGT}
    PK {TGT}
```

```
-- Group GRP is targeting target TGT.
--
group_target {GRP, TGT}
          PK {GRP, TGT}

FK1 {GRP} REFERENCES group  {GRP}
FK2 {TGT} REFERENCES target {TGT}
```

```sql
-- Subgroup number SG# of group GRP
-- is targeting target TGT.
--
CREATE VIEW subgroup_target (GRP, SG#, TGT)
AS
SELECT a.GRP
     , a.SG#
     , b.TGT
FROM subgroup     AS a
JOIN group_target AS b on b.GRP = a.GRP ;
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
```

```
Using suffix # to save on screen space.
OK for SQL Server and Oracle, for others use _NO.
For example, rename SG# to SG_NO.
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the syntax in the first four code samples. Is that valid SQL? Also, how is the `subgroup_target` view used to enforce that the number of `targets` and `subgroup_targets` are always equal?

Comment: @shoe (1/2) RE syntax: just a logical design with as little "noise" as possible.
The idea is simply not to store subgroup targets, but derive them, hence the view. For example: group `GRP = 11` has subgroups (`SG#`) `[1 .. 3]`, and targets `[20 .. 25]`. Because each subgroup is *identified* by `{GRP, SG#}` -- `(11,1), (11,2), (11,3)` -- each of these subgroups has exactly the same targets as the group.

Comment: @shoe (2/2) To get targets for subgroup (11,2):

`SELECT TGT FROM subgroup_target WHERE GRP=11 AND SG# = 2;`

returns `(20), (21), (22), (23), 24), (25)`.

Comment: I see. But if the `subgroup_targets` are derived, where do you propose I store the data they contain?

Comment: @shoe (A 1/2) If *subgroup_targets* are different from *group_targets* then this model is wrong (obviously) and you will have to manage required rules from the app. Current SQL implementations do not support assertions (DB-wide constraints: CREATE ASSERTION) that you would need to implement this.

Comment: @shoe (A 2/2) The procedure to add a new target (from the app) may look something like:
1. Obtain all subgroups for a group.
2. Crate insert statements for the group and all the matching subgroups.
3. Start transaction `BEGIN TRANSACTION`
4. Send all insert statements.
5. Check for errors.
6. If no error issue COMMIT; else ROLLBACK.
This way you will be able to add all targets or none.